# Android stuttered Audio

Tags: android

I have a button when I clicked in it shows me an slide with a picture and plays an audio from my sd card with this code:

```
public void buttonClickHandler(View v) {
    this.onClickNextDiapositiva();
    Diapositiva diapo1 = this.getDiapoActual();
    try {
        if (diapo1.tieneSonido()) {
           String sndPath = ZIP_SND_PATH + diapo1.getSonido().getNombre();
           InputStream isSonido = this.getTutorFile().getFile(sndPath);

           this.audioPlayer = new StreamingMediaPlayer(this);
           this.audioPlayer.startStreaming(isSonido);   
        }   else if (diapo1.tieneVideo()) {
           if (!diapo1.tieneImagen()) {
           String imgPath = ZIP_FONDOS_PATH + "fondo_video.png";
           cargarImagen(imgPath);
           }
        }
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
       Log.e("mostrarDiapositiva", ex.getMessage());
       Toast
       .makeText(this, "Error: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
       .show();
    }
    break;
```

}

the fact is that the code works, the slide is changed and de audio played but it starts and when less than one second is played it started again, it´s like if it was stuttered.

Any idea why is this happening? thanks too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MediaPlayer instead of StreamingMediaPlayer

for example:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();  
// when you want to play the sound stored in nodeaudio: 
// nodeaudio is a path like /min/sdcard/soundfile 

if (nodeaudio == null || nodeaudio.trim().equals("")) {                 
    mp.reset();             
} else {                 
    try {                 
        mp.reset();                 
        mp.setDataSource(nodeaudio);                 
        mp.prepare();                 
        mp.start();                 
    }                 
    catch(Exception e) {                     
        Log.e("Play sound ERROR", e.toString());                     
        e.printStackTrace();                 
    }             
}
```