# How store a video while streaming that?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, streaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS video streaming and storing on device afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290251/ios-video-streaming-and-storing-on-device-afterwards)

I found same question not answer.

[iOS video streaming and storing on device afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290251/ios-video-streaming-and-storing-on-device-afterwards)

1. A video will be downloading from server.
2. While downloading, I want streaming it.

Is it possible?