# Playing Video into UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have read several posts here about live streaming `video/audio`. Unfortunately it seems that there is not any "good" solution.

I want same functionality for video which is provided `SDWebImageView` for images.

Right now, I am using following code:-

```
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
```

But when I scrolled `tableview`, all videos **download again and again**. So How **can I stop that** downloading?

Is there any better solution for playing video into `UITableView`? Same **Facebook, Instagram, and Vine Apps doing**?

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController and MPMoviePlayerViewController are deprecated since iOS 9 onwards. You should use some other player controller. 
Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/ and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerViewController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMoviePlayerViewController

Comment: Ok. Then I will be use AVPlayerViewController . But my issue is how can I stop that again and again downloading that video due to tableview..

Comment: I think this answer will help..http://stackoverflow.com/a/14961854/5316422

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated in iOS 9. Use AVPlayerViewController instead.

Comment: I know that. I also used this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31277658/3908884.
But my issue is how can I stop downloading video every time when I scrolled that cell.

Comment: Where have you implemented this code ?

Comment: Into my app. I want to make feeds Listing screen with video functionality. Still I am not getting exact solution.. If you have, please help me..

Answer (score 9):

Don't use `MPMoviePlayerController`, use `AVFoundation`'s `AVPlayer`.

Additionally, don't couple the downloading of your asset to your `UITableViewCell` subclass.  Use an additional data source to download and manage the video assets.

There are a few ways you can do this.

1. Keep a data source array of `AVPlayerItem` objects initialized by URL.  Instead of loading the asset each time you scroll to a cell, just load the `AVPlayerItem` into the cell's player, and remove it when you scroll away.
2. If you need to persist the video data, consider downloading each video to a temporary file in your Documents directory.  When the file has finished downloading, load that data into an `AVAsset` using its `initWithURL:` method and point the URL to your local file.  When ready, you can load your asset into an `AVPlayerItem` using `initWithAsset:` and play the video.

Comment: I want to pause the video, when user scrolls down and play it again, can it be done by point no 1.

Comment: Is there any thirdparty framwork by which I can auto play video in cells.

Answer (score 7):

When you scroll table view then method `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is fired (actually every time when cell will be visible this method is called). I believe that you are allocating and initializing yours MediaPlayer in this method and that's why video is downloaded again. You could try to add array and store already created cells in it (some kind of cache). Then your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` should check if it has sth cached for actual index. If yes then show cached cell. If no then it should create cell, alloc, and init player and then store cell in cache.

My ViewController has property: `NSMutableDictionary *cache;` and in `ViewDidLoad` I have: `cache = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`
My `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellId = @"myCellId";

    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

    if ([cache objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%lu", indexPath.row]] != nil) {
        cell = [cache objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%lu", indexPath.row]];
    } else {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
        playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"]];
        [cell addSubview:playerViewController.view];
        [cache setValue:cell forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%lu", indexPath.row]];
    }

    return cell; 
}
```

It works for me. Of course you need to use your own datasource etc.

Comment: I already tried this. But not working like I want.. If you have sample code for this, then Please Provide. Its better for me.. Check comment of @Meharoof Najeeb under question..

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
    let videoURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov")
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = cell.bounds
    cell.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
    return cell
}
```