# Media Player stream url, then play next url

Tags: android, audio, streaming, media-player, filenames

I'm currently have a media player that is streaming an mp3 file. When that file is done, what is the code so that it goes to the next url/mp3?

And also, is there code to get the name of the file and display it? how would I go about doing that?

thanks

**EDIT**

see my code below:

```
package com.example.m3uplayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;

public class m3uPlayer extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //

        //http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24535120/AfroJack-UMF11-clip2.mp3

        //http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24535120/Avicii%20clip%201.mp3


        Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24535120/AfroJack-UMF11-clip2.mp3");

        MediaPlayer sdrPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            sdrPlayer.setDataSource(this, myUri);//"http://mp1.somafm.com:8032");
            sdrPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            sdrPlayer.prepare(); //don't use prepareAsync for mp3 playback
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sdrPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer sdrPlayer) {
        Uri myUri5 = Uri.parse("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24535120/Avicii%20clip%201.mp3");

        try {
            sdrPlayer.setDataSource(this, myUri5);
            sdrPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            sdrPlayer.prepare(); //don't use prepareAsync for mp3 playback
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sdrPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register an [OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) with the media player. When it receives its callback notification, you need to call `reset()`, `setDataSource`, and `prepare()` on the media player for the next URL.

I don't believe there is anything in the api to tell you what data source a media player is using. You need to keep track of that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ted. So there is no way to have the title of the song appear when that song is playing from the URL?

Comment: Also, kind of a random question...Is it possible to create an array with muliple URLs inside and have the media player play the array? If it is possible, would i still have to set an on completion listener? thanks

Comment: There's nothing in the api that I know of to extract the song title. The only thing I can suggest is processing the mp3 stream yourself and then feeding it to the media player through a local file. There's experimental code to do that in Reuben Scratton's answer to [this query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343730/mediaplayer-stutters-at-start-of-mp3-playback). As to your second question, I think you'll have to step through the url array yourself using an on completion listener.

Comment: hmmm ok. thanks for the link. So i have been trying with the code above and it is not playing the second url. any suggesstions? it just replays the first song

Comment: The idea would be that in your OnCompletionListener, you would go on to the next url. Your code always calls `setDataSource` with the same one.

Comment: I could be wrong, but can't you not use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.TrackInfo.html to get the track info?

Comment: @dorien - That can be used, but only if you're running Jelly Bean. It doesn't exist below API level 16.