# How to figure out the number of bytes downloaded in mediaplayer android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am streaming from an mp3 stream using the `MediaPlayer`.

I set the datasource, call `preparyAsync()`, call `start()` on the `onPrepared()` callback.

Now I want to know the number of bytes downloaded by the mediaplayer when streaming a song.

Is there a way to track the number of bytes?

Its not going to be one song but instead an mp3 stream.

Comment: You can be notified of buffering progress (via `setOnBufferingUpdateListener()`) but I don't know any straightforward way to get the underlying network info

Comment: If you _somehoe_ know the size of the mp3, then you can figure it out using `setOnBufferingUpdateListener`.

Comment: the buffered listener only gives me the percentage. unfortunately its not one song, its an mp3 stream.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to know the number of bytes of downloaded compressed data, not the number the bytes of uncompressed data inside MediaPlayer which is proportional to the lenght of audio played. (The compressed data may not be proportional in case of using VBR for example).

To get the number of bytes of downloaded compressed data you need to count the bytes of stream downloaded by MediaPlayer, but I believe the only way to have access to the stream downloaded is to implement a local streamproxy that feeds the MediaPlayer, or a second solution is to save the stream to a local file and open this file with MediaPlayer, but the later solution has some limitations as MediaPlayer locks the local file and data cannot be appended.

For the first solution see this solution on how to implement a proxy to feed MediaPlayer: [MediaPlayer stutters at start of mp3 playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343730/mediaplayer-stutters-at-start-of-mp3-playback/5432091#5432091)