# Android - Play a song that is still downloading

Tags: java, android, streaming, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I'm creating an app in which multiple devices can connect to each other in a LAN and play songs from each other's device.

Right now, when device A requests a song from device B, B sends the song file back to A over a socket. Once the song finishes downloading, A starts playing it using `MediaPlayer`.

Now the problem with this is that even on a high speed LAN, it can take a couple of seconds to finish fetching the song, so there's a noticeable delay between selecting a song and it's playback actually starting.

I want to find a way to play a song while it's still being downloaded. Here are some possible solutions I found, but wasn't able to explore for certain reasons:

1. In the `MediaPlayer` documentation, I noticed a constructor that takes a [`MediaDataSource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDataSource.html) implementation allowing me to manually return parts of the media file whenever the MediaPlayer requires it so I could hold off returning a byte until it finishes downloading (if it hasn't finished downloading already), effectively acting like a "buffering" action. It seemed like a solution but unfortunately, my app's minSdk is set to 16 and `MediaDataSource` is for 23 and above only, so I couldn't try it out.
2. One option was to use `MediaPlayer`'s `setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length)` method. This would allow me to tell the MediaPlayer to only play up to a certain byte of the song. That way, I could wait for more parts of the file (or the entire file) to become available, and then use `setNextMediaPlayer()` and pass in a new MediaPlayer object that prepares the entire song and is made to seek up to the point where the previous media player object will stop playing so that there's a seamless transition.
   But there's another problem with this. I need to be able to calculate the millisecond position that would be reached at that last specified byte of the first incomplete media player object. Otherwise I wouldn't know what position to seek the next media player object to in order to get a seamless transition. This calculation seems impossible for lossy formats.
3. I don't really know if this option will work or not, I'm just making assumptions. I noticed that `setDataSource()` takes a Uri. If that Uri points to a file on the phone, the media player just loads the entire file. But if the Uri points to an audio file on the internet that needs to be streamed, it figures that out on it's own and it handles all the details of downloading and buffering. So what I want to know is, is it possible to expose the song on device B as a Uri to device A so that media player just treats it as if it's a song on the internet? All this time I was using sockets and manually copying a file from one device to another so I have no idea how this would work. Could anyone explain if this is possible?

   There's actually a reason why I haven't been exploring ways to "stream" a song from one device to another. That's because I want to song to be cached on device B so that later if I switch to another song and then back the previously played song from device A, it shouldn't have to stream it again. It should just play the cached copy.
4. Finally, I came across `ExoPlayer`. It seems to provide a large amount of customization. It seems like I could make custom implementations of it's classes to handle all the buffering. But the documentation and examples are few and far too complicated for me. I have no idea how to pull it off. Is this solution too complex for what I want to achieve?

Hope someone can point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using an answer from here:

[MediaPlayer stutters at start of mp3 playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343730/mediaplayer-stutters-at-start-of-mp3-playback/5432091#5432091)

This solution sets up a local server that the MediaPlayer can use to stream the file. The server only sends bytes to the MediaPlayer while those bytes are available. Otherwise, it blocks until more bytes are available. Thus the MediaPlayer buffers it as if it were a file from a web server.

I took the same class provided in that answer and just tweaked it to fit my situation.